# Where is my friend right now?

Tags: word, knowledge

A friend of mine is travelling the world and likes to send cryptic messages about where he is, I think he enjoys challenging me. Anyway here is the latest message, can anyone here help me figure it out?

```
 My 1st is the capital and my 4th is not: 41.85-12.50

 My 2nd is falling behind: 35.68-139.69

 My 3rd is found thrice, but is not my 5th: 10.65-61.50

 My 5th is exactly half: 45.42-75.70
```

Comment: Nice first puzzle! +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Gintas has already found, ...

> the numbers refer to longitudes (E or W) and latitudes (N) of the capital cities of:
>
>  Rome — **ITALY**
>  Tokyo — **JAPAN**
>  Port of Spain — **TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO**
>  Ottawa — **CANADA**

The answer can be found in ...

> ... the names of the corresponding countries:

My 1st is the capital and my 4th is not.

> **I**: I is the first letter of Italy; not sure about the fourth, which I think should also be an I. Is it because a small l, the fourth letter of Italy, looks like a capitalI in a sans-serif font?

My 2nd is falling behind

> **N**: the last letter of Japan.

My 3rd is found thrice, but is not my 5th

> **D**: D and A occur three times in Trinidad and Tobago, and the 5th is A, see below

My 5th is exactly half

> **A**: Half of the letters in Canada are As.

Anyway, I think your friend is in...

> ... **INDIA**.

Comment: Well done :) Was using the same approach, but for the city, not country names... :D

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, well done.

Comment: I think, the first line means, 1st letter of India is capital and 4th is not. Both are **i**

Comment: @GintasK: I think we had the same idea at the same time. When I saw that half of the letters of Canada were the same, I knew I was on to something.

Comment: So was my assumption about the small l that looks like a capital I correct? Or is @Techidiot right? Or is ther an altogether different parsing?

Comment: Anyway, I liked the puzzle. It took a bit of lateral thinking twice (the coords from numbers and countries from capitals) to solve, but it wasn't obscure or too hard.

Comment: @MOehm My plan for for people to recognize the capital of Italy as capital i and the 4th as the opposite, ie lower case i

Comment: Ah, okay, so "capital" is doing double duty: It indicates the first letter and a capital letter. I didn't get that, but I had enough letters to guess the answer. Techidiot got it, though, so it was just me being a bit thick.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial Answer**

> The number bit looks like coordinates:
>
>  1) 41.85-12.50: **Rome** (41.85 Lat 12.50 Lon)
>
>  2) 35.68-139.69: **Tokyo** (35.68 Lat 139.69 Lon)
>
>  3) 10.65-61.50: **Port of Spain** (10.65 Lat -61.50 Lon)
>
>  4) 45.42-75.70:  **Ottawa** (45.42 Lat -75.70 Lon)

Then

> Then @M-Oehm was faster than me :)

Comment: You are on the right track